# C# Form Multiline HTML in String gives error

Tags: c#, html, string

Good day everyone,

i want to send an email with parameters like i have my HTML(multiline string) and some data that stored in string but when i try to do like this;

```
<td style='border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000' colspan=3 align='center' valign=bottom><b><font color='#000000'>"+MY DATA STRING+"</font></b></td>
```

it gives error like this;

[image: here is error]

What I have tried:

without custom value with string, there is no error when like this but i need custom values that comes from database to string;

```
<td style='border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000' align='center' valign=bottom><font color='#000000'>Agency Name</font></td>
```

Comment: Because this is not valid xhtml (that means it still might be correctly interpreted by a browser). Attributes with value need double-quotes around the value - they can't be without any or with single-quotes.

Comment: is this means i cant fill my cell's with custom values ? if is how can i handle it ?

Comment: Take a look at the Errors window (Menu View -> Errors) to see a description of the actual error, or hover over the code that is underlined in red. That way to can see what the actual error is/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all from the partial html that you pasted, you must change `valign=bottom` to `valign='bottom'`

By looking at the screenshot, I see that you are creating the html markup in your .cs file.
If you really must do it like this, then at least use the syntax below without concatenation.

```
string aStringVariable = "Hello world!";
string html = $@"
...
<td style='border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000' colspan=3 align='center' valign='bottom'><b><font color='#000000'>{"MY DATA STRING"}</font></b></td>
<td style='border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000' colspan=3 align='center' valign='bottom'><b><font color='#000000'>{aStringVariable}</font></b></td>
...
";
```

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, using css would shorten your manually typed html by a lot. Also you are using a lot of obsolete html elements (like font) and attributes (like align and valign). I didn't mention these in the answer since it was not related to your question. But everyday is a good opportunity to learn something new. ;)